# Why the partx cannot output the debug info with LIBBLKID_DEBUG enabled ？

Tags: rhel, libblkid

We have run the partx with LIBBLKID_DEBUG enabled on many RHEL/CentOS,  but all output without their corresponding debug details！

```
# 
# 
# LIBBLKID_DEBUG=0xffff partx  /dev/cciss/c0d0
# 1:        63-   208844 (   208782 sectors,    106 MB)
# 2:    208845-585858419 (585649575 sectors, 299852 MB)
# 3:         0-       -1 (        0 sectors,      0 MB)
# 4:         0-       -1 (        0 sectors,      0 MB)
# 
# 
# 
# export LIBBLKID_DEBUG=0xffff 
# 
# 
# 
#  partx  /dev/cciss/c0d0
# 1:        63-   208844 (   208782 sectors,    106 MB)
# 2:    208845-585858419 (585649575 sectors, 299852 MB)
# 3:         0-       -1 (        0 sectors,      0 MB)
# 4:         0-       -1 (        0 sectors,      0 MB)
# 
#
```

Comment: I'm able to get the debug output on my CentOS 7 system. However, it seems to be printing to the stderr stream. Are you discarding stderr, by any chance?

Comment: I have rechecked it,  but still unavailable！

Comment: Finally I have to use the open source code from mirrors.kernel.org,  which resolved my this problem！
Notes：it seems that only the open source code of util-linux could normally output the debug details！